# Calculating angle of rotation of orthogonal 3x3 matrix

Tags: geometry, matrices

Regarding the matrix in Q3b here: http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2013/2637/5/13sh2.pdf

I've worked out the axis of rotation by finding out the line of invariant points, but I'm not sure how to work out the angle of rotation. Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an appropriate orthonormal basis, the matrix of a rotation  always takes this form:

$$
R =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta  &  -\sin\theta &   0 \\
\sin\theta  &   \cos\theta &   0 \\
0           &       0      &   1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Here, $\theta$ is precisely the angle of rotation. Now, since equivalent matrices have the same trace, you just equate:

$$
\mathrm{tr} B = \mathrm{tr} R = 1 + 2\cos\theta
$$

and you find out your angle (up to a sign).

Comment: Great example of invariants at work :)

Comment: Very nice answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer - what's an orthonormal basis?

Comment: An orthonormal basis is one having all its vectors unitary and mutually orthogonal.